# Question with using time series in R for forecasting via example

Tags: r, forecast

Im working through [this example](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/sweep/vignettes/SW01_Forecasting_Time_Series_Groups.html). However, when I begin investigating the tk_ts output I don't think it is taking the start/end data Im entering correctly, but am unsure as to what the proper input is if I want it to start at 12-31-2019 and end at 7-17-2020:

```
daily_cases2 <- as_tibble(countrydatescases) %>%
    mutate(Date = as_date(date)) %>%
    group_by(country, Date) %>%
    summarise(total_cases = sum(total_cases))

  daily_cases2$total_cases <- as.double(daily_cases2$total_cases)
  
  # Nest
  daily_cases2_nest <- daily_cases2 %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    tidyr::nest()
  
# TS
  daily_cases2_ts <- daily_cases2_nest %>%
    mutate(data.ts = purrr::map(.x  = data, 
                         .f       = tk_ts, 
                         select   = -Date,
                         start    = 2019-12-31,
                         freq     = 1))
```

Here is what I get when I examine it closely:

[image]

[image]

When I go through the example steps with these parameters the issue is also then seen in the subsequent graph:

[image]

I've tried varying the frequency and start parameters and its just not making sense. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want a yearly (`freq=1`), monthly (`freq=12)`, or daily (`freq=365`) series? If yearly, then your `start` is wrong. If daily, then your `freq` is wrong, as well as your `start`.

Answer (score 2):

You've given the start and end dates, but you haven't said what frequency you want. Given that you want the series to start at the end of 2019 and end in the middle of July, 2020, I'm guessing you want a **daily** time series. In that case, the code should be:

```
daily_cases2_ts <- daily_cases2_nest %>%
    mutate(data.ts = purrr::map(.x  = data, 
                         .f       = tk_ts, 
                         select   = -Date,
                         start    = c(2019, 365),  # day 365 of year 2019
                         freq     = 365))          # daily series
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Edward, when I do that I get something that looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/G1eeYy9  which doesnt seem right...

Comment: When does your time series actually start? While you can use the `end` argument to "subset" the series prematurely, the `start` argument must specify the _actual_ start. You can't use it to subset (filter) the data. So if your data doesn't start at the end of 2019, you'll have to `filter` it first.

Comment: Im using this for a data frame where there are multiple factors with different start dates. Does that mean I need to make separate ts objects then?

the max/min are 12-31-2019 and 7-17-2020

Comment: You mean the min/max (not max/min). No need to make separate ts objects. But it now sounds like you need a multiple time-series object, similar to the `EuStockMarkets` dataset.